# fetch_assoc return with missing rows

Tags: php, mysql

I read some questions from a database table and in an inner loop I fetch the possible answers from another table with a foreign key.

The shown answer rows should be a fixed number of 5 but it always return only 4 rows, the first row of the *answers* in the inner loop seems always to be missing.

$_POST['nbr'] is the number of questions

$_POST['type']  is the type of question

$row is for the question $row2 is for the suggested answers related to

This is the code

```
<?php 
 // session
 session_start();
   ?>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<title>passé un examen</title>

</head>
<body>

<form method = "post" action ="" >
<b>Specialité : </b> 

<select name="sp">
<?php 
require_once("connect_db.php");
$result = $connect->query("Select nom from specialite");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<option>'.$row['nom'].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>

<b>choisi le nombre de questions : </b><input type="number" name="nbr"             step="1" />
<b>type de question : </b>

<select name="type">
  <option value="qcm" >QCM</option>
  <option value="qcs">QCS</option>
  <option value="qc2">LES DEUX</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="générer" />
</form>

<?php
$count=1;
$count2=1;
$type;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if($_POST['nbr'] <= 0)
    die('choisi au moin une question');

$_SESSION['type']=$_POST['type'];
$_SESSION['nbr_qst']=$_POST['nbr'];
echo '<form action="" method="post" >';
//TYPE QCS
if($_POST['type']=="qcs"){

    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE specialite =     '".$_POST['sp']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$_POST['nbr']." ");
    if(($result->num_rows == 0) ||($result->num_rows < $_POST['nbr']))
        die('questions dans cette specialité est insuffusant');
    echo '<p><b>Question QCS</b></p>'.PHP_EOL;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo 'Question '.$count.' : '.$row['question'].'<br>'.PHP_EOL;

        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['question'].'"     name="q'.$count.'" ';
        $result2=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponses WHERE     id_Q=".$row['id_Q']);
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

            echo $count2.'- '.$row2['reponse'].'<input type="radio" name="srep'.$count.'" value="'.$row2['iscorrect'].'" /><br>'.PHP_EOL;
            $count2++;
        }
        $count2=1;
        $count++;
    }


}
//Type QCM
if($_POST['type']=="qcm"){
    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM question_qcm WHERE specialite =     '".$_POST['sp']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$_POST['nbr']." ");
    if(($result->num_rows == 0) ||($result->num_rows < $_POST['nbr']))
        die('questions dans cette specialité est insuffusant');

    echo '<p><b>Question QCM</b></p>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo 'Question '.$count.' : '.$row['question'].'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
        // get the question primary key
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id_qcm'].'" name="q'.$count.'" ';
        $result2=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponse_qcm WHERE id_qcm=".$row['id_qcm']);
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $count2.'- '.$row2['reponse'].'<input type="checkbox" name="mrep'.$count.$count2.'" value="'.$row2['id'].'" /><br>'.PHP_EOL;
            $count2++;
        }
        $count2=1;
        $count++;
    }

}

//Type de deux
if($_POST['type']=="qc2"){
    $nbr=$_POST['nbr']/2;
    if($_POST['nbr']==1)
        die('choisi au moin deux question pour le type <b>LES DEUX</b>'.PHP_EOL);


    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE specialite = '".$_POST['sp']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".(int)$nbr." ");
    if(($result->num_rows == 0) )
        die('questions QCS dans cette specialité est insuffusant');

    echo '<p><b>Question QCS</b></p>'.PHP_EOL;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo 'Question '.$count.' : '.$row['question'].'<br>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id_Q'].'" name="sq'.$count.'" '.PHP_EOL;
        $result2=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponses WHERE id_Q=".$row['id_Q']);
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $count2.'- '.$row2['reponse'].'<input type="radio" name="srep'.$count.'" /><br>'.PHP_EOL;
            $count2++;
        }
        $count2=1;
        $count++;
    }







    $nbr = ($_POST['nbr']/2)+($_POST['nbr']%2);

    $result1 = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM question_qcm WHERE specialite = '".$_POST['sp']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".(int)$nbr." ");
    if(($result1->num_rows == 0))
        die('questions QCM dans cette specialité est insuffusant');


    echo '<p><b>Question QCM</b></p>';
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){

        echo 'Question '.$count.' : '.$row['question'].'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id_qcm'].'" name="mq'.$count.'" ';
        $result2=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponse_qcm WHERE id_qcm=".$row['id_qcm']);
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $count2.'- '.$row2['reponse'].'<input type="radio" name="mrep'.$count.'" /><br>'.PHP_EOL;
            $count2++;
        }
        $count2=1;
        $count++;
    }

}





echo '<input type="submit" name="valider" value="valider" />';





}
?>

<br><br>

</form>










<?php
if(isset($_POST['valider'])){

//IF THERE's NOT a GENERATION YET

//IF ALL Question are answered


    $Score=0;

    //TYPE QCS
    if($_SESSION['type']=="qcs"){
    $Score_Finale = $_SESSION['nbr_qst'];
    for($i=1;$i<=$_SESSION['nbr_qst'];$i++){

    if(isset($_POST['srep'.$i])){

        $Score+=$_POST['srep'.$i];
        }



    }

    die('<p><b>Ton Score est : '.$Score.'/'.$Score_Finale.'</b></p>');  
    }
    /*
    //TYPE QCM (deux boule c tt  nbrquest,5)
if($_SESSION['type']=="qcm"){
    $Score_Finale = $_SESSION['nbr_qst'];
    for($i=1;$i<=$_SESSION['nbr_qst'];$i++){
        for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++){

                    if(isset($_POST['mrep'.$i.$j])){

                        $result = $connect->query("Select * FROM reponse_qcm     where id=".$_POST['mrep'.$i.$j]);
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $Score = $row['bareme'];

                    }


            }



    }


die('<p><b>Ton Score est : '.$Score.'/'.$Score_Finale.'</b></p>');  
}
*/

}


// Il FAUT vérifier que le bareme totale de question est < 1 est la bonne     réponse tjr = 1
?>



</body>
</html>
```

Screenshots of the database

[questions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwcN1.png)

[responses table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xdjU.png)

Screenshot of the browser result

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDxgQ.png)

**After a while i found a solution**

instead of doing two loops, i did create a function for the second loop and return the responses of each question

the function :

```
function getRepS($id){

require_once("connect_db.php");
global $connect;
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponses WHERE id_Q=".$id);
$count=0;
$Send;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $Send[$count] = $row;
    $count++;
  }
  return $Send;
}
```

the main script :

```
    if($_POST['type']=="qcs"){
        echo '################';
    $result2=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM reponses WHERE id_Q=7");
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

            echo $row2['reponse'].'<br>';


        }
    echo '################';


    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE specialite = '".$_POST['sp']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".(int)$_POST['nbr']." ");
    if(($result->num_rows == 0) ||($result->num_rows < $_POST['nbr']))
        die('questions dans cette specialité est insuffusant');
    echo '<p><b>Question QCS</b></p>'.PHP_EOL;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo 'Question '.$count.' : '.$row['question'].'<br>'.PHP_EOL;

        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['question'].'" name="q'.$count.'" ';

        $row2=getRepS($row['id_Q']);

        $count2=0;
        while($count2 != count($row2)){

            echo ($j+1).'- '.$row2[$j]['reponse'].'<input type="radio" name="srep'.$count.'" value="'.$row2[$j]['iscorrect'].'" /><br>'.PHP_EOL;
            $count2++;
        }






        $count++;
    }


}
```

Comment: Which row is having 5 rows ? Row1 or row2?

Comment: $row is for the question
$row2 is for the suggested answers related to the $row

Comment: Code not reproducible due to missing example data and parameter values. Please improve your question. There is an edit link below you question.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and expose the results. Please show a small data table which is not selected as expected.

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error. Sure `$_POST['nbr']` is 5 or more?

Comment: a string i did a casting now but still the same

Comment: $_POST['nbr'] is for the number of question. the questions are fine 
but their answers should be 5 as in the database but only 4 appears in every displayed question

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone look at "the output" picture above

Answer (score 2):

Since codes in comments are not very readable, I write suggestions to find the error as an answer. I'll delete it if it won't be helpful.

On your development server (**not** the production server!) add a file `.htaccess` (or edit an existing) in your web root directory.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value error_log  /path/to/your/webproject/phperror.log
```

This should show and log any errors in php.

View the **source code** of the generated HTML page and post it here.

Install [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/download.php) on your development server. XAMPP already does contain xdebug. Use an IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse or PhpStorm to take advantage from xdebug's debugging features. You can trace your code in single steps statement by statement watching the current variable states. Once set up, you won't want to work without any more.